# Add a many-to-one predicate to a LINQ-to-SQL query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, many-to-many, where-clause

How do I filter an `IQueryable<T>` LINQ-to-SQL query on a related many-to-many table? For example, given an `IQueryable<Product>` where each `Product` has many Tags that are stored in a related `ProductTags` table, I want to filter on the association of one or more tags.

A document store or comma-separated value on `Product` would make this simpler, but the data are stored in denormalised SQL tables.

For bonus points, what if the `ProductTags` table is just a mapping-table and I also need to retrieve data from the `Tags` table?

This is what the schema looks like:

```
Products <-> ProductTags <-> Tags
```

**Update:** Looks like I want to filter [against an `EntitySet<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9320962/198927).

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a list of tag names, say `tagNames`, you can do something like:

```
var query = from p in Products
            from t in p.ProductTags.Select(pc => pc.Tag)
            where tagNames.Contains(t.TagName)
            select new { p.ProductName, t.TagName };
```

This will get you all `Product` that have at least one of the tags in `tagNames` and you can select data from `Product` or `Tag`.

Note that this is not necessarily a distinct list of products.

If the tags are stored in `ProductTags` directly, the query changes into

```
var query = from p in Products
            from t in p.ProductTags
            where tagNames.Contains(t.TagName)
            select new { p.ProductName, t.TagName };
```

Comment: What SQL would this generate? A subquery as expected? Does it avoid an N+1 query?

Comment: This will produce a subquery. However, if for instance you'd only `select` products, and access their tags afterwards, you'd get n+1. To prevent that you should use DataLoadOptions.